# Alert shows message without pressing Alert Button

Tags: react-native

I am using this code to display my input values by pressing a button. But whenever I enters a text it automatically display an alert box of it as soon as I type any input to  components.

I wanted to display alertbox, when I press "Add User" button. What's wrong with it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput,Alert, Button} from 'react-native';


export default class myTest extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {firstName: 'your name', lastName: 'your last', email: 'enter your email'};
  }
  onPressButton(){
    let firstName = this.state.firstName;
    let lastName = this.state.lastName;

    Alert.alert("You've Entered" + firstName+"\n "+lastName+"\n");
  }

  render()
  {


      return (
          <View>
            <Text>ENTER YOUR DETAILS:</Text>
            <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="FirstName"
          onChangeText={(firstName) => this.setState({firstName})}
        />
           <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          onChangeText={(lastName) => this.setState({lastName})}
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 30}}>
          firstName: {this.state.firstName}{'\n'}
          lastName: {this.state.lastName} 
        </Text>
        <Button title="Add User" onPress={this.onPressButton()}/>

          </View>
      );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Button tag, replace `onPress = {this.onPressButton()}` with `onPress = {() => this.onPressButton()}`

Comment: Thanks I was trying something like that. But I know I was doing some mistake

Comment: No need to create a new anonymous function on each render, as you're not passing any parameters. This will do the trick: `onPress = {this.onPressButton}`

Comment: @ErikHaiderForsén Sorry I tried your version earlier posting this question, however it didn't work out